# custoomizing success_message in SuccessMessageMixin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

Cant get my head around 1 thing:

In Django documentation said that you can do something like that when use SuccessMessageMixin:

success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"

where (name) is a field of the form   used by a View.

I am trying to add name of the user in the success message   in PasswordResetView.  PasswordResetView has  by default form called  “PasswordResetForm” and this form has only 1 field “email” that I have already used.
Example --- success_message = "Email with the instructions has been sent to your email - %(email)s"

```py
# original Django code
class PasswordResetView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    email_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_email.html’
    extra_email_context = None
    form_class = PasswordResetForm   # this form

# original Django code
class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)  # this field
```

I am trying to somehow do something like :

```py
success_message = "Email with the instructions has been sent to your email - %(email)s, %(username)s"
```

but question where is to get username if this form has only 1 field “email”?

Interesting moment that  PasswordResetForm has a method called get_users(), where we could get username from:

```py
def get_users(self, email):
    """Given an email, return matching user(s) who should receive a reset.

    This allows subclasses to more easily customize the default policies
    that prevent inactive users and users with unusable passwords from
    resetting their password.
    """
    active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(**{
        '%s__iexact' % UserModel.get_email_field_name(): email,
        'is_active': True,
    })
    return (u for u in active_users if u.has_usable_password())
```

It seems  as an interesting  task but I cant comprehend how to combine it all together to be able to add username into the success message.

Have tried following:

```py
class PRForm(PasswordResetForm):
    custom_user = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), show_hidden_initial=True, initial=???) # some connections to def get_users(self, email) maybe???
```

Make new form based on the default form and add there hidden field  custom_user a, but I don’t know what type in in the initials. Then I would be able to use this field in success_message potentially.
What do you recon about this method or it is completely dumb?

Anyway , if someone has any idea I would be glad to hear it.
I can live  without this task, no problems, but it seems very interesting for me to solve it.

FIGURED IT OUT MYSELF:

```py
   class PRForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not ExtraUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True, is_activated=True).exists():
            msg = "There is no user registered with the specified E-Mail address."
            self.add_error('email', msg)
        else:
            current_user = ExtraUser.objects.get(email__iexact=email, is_active=True, is_activated=True)
            if current_user:
                self.cleaned_data["username"] = current_user
        return email
```

and now it is possible to write success_message like this:

```py
success_message = "Dear %(username)s , email with the instructions has been sent to your email - %(email)s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself:

```py
class PRForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not ExtraUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True, is_activated=True).exists():
            msg = "There is no user registered with the specified E-Mail address."
            self.add_error('email', msg)
        else:
            current_user = ExtraUser.objects.get(email__iexact=email, is_active=True, is_activated=True)
            if current_user:
                self.cleaned_data["username"] = current_user
        return email
```

1) define current user

2) pass it to a cleaned_data as Django takes this %()s type tags from the cleaned data of the form